# Confused in the capabilities of Power Gem in Munchkin:Marvel

Tags: munchkin

Does the power of Power Gem really means that you can use all powers regardless of its rank requirement?

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is such that you're asking this question? Your question appears to be "does this card do what it says it does", while we'd generally expect to see some reason you'd doubt it working like that.

Comment: You may get faster help if you include the text or a picture for those away from their games=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card itself reads "You may have any number of powers, regardless of rank". What's your question again?